# Merging data frames: 1 column in one data frame can match 2 columns in the other

Tags: r, join, dplyr, merge

I want to merge two data frames containing different versions of species names: The first data frame (dat_a) contains a bunch of columns containing the different possible species names, the second a column with species names plus some value columns (dat_b). So **complete_name3** in dat_b can either match to **complete_name1** or **complete_name2** in dat_a as I don't know which version of the name is used in dat_b.

So I need something like...

```
dat_new <- left_join(dat_a, dat_b, by = c("complete_name1" | "complete_name2" = "complete_name3"))
```

or

```
dat_new <- left_join(dat_a, dat_b, by = c("complete_name1" = "complete_name3" | "complete_name2" = "complete_name3"))
```

Is there a possibility to do this?

Data:

```
dat_a <- tibble::tribble(
  ~genus,   ~species,        ~complete_name2,        ~complete_name1,
  "Galium", "mollugo",       "Galium mollugo",       "Galium mollugo aggr.",
  "Galium", "boreale",       "Galium boreale",       "Galium boreale",
  "Galium", "aparine",       "Galium aparine",       "Galium aparine",
  "Rosa",   "canina",        "Rosa canina",          "Rosa canina aggr.",
  "Galium", "pumilum",       "Galium pumilum",       "Galium pumilum aggr.",
  "Betula", "pendula",       "Betula pendula",       "Betula pendula aggr.",
  "Rosa",   "tomentosa",     "Rosa tomentosa",       "Rosa tomentosa aggr.",
  "Galium", "anisophyllon",  "Galium anisophyllon",  "Galium pumilum aggr.",
  "Galium", "thunbergianum", "Galium thunbergianum", NA_character_,
  "Galium", "rotundifolium", "Galium rotundifolium", "Galium rotundifolium",
  "Galium", "lucidum",       "Galium lucidum",       "Galium lucidum",
  "Betula", "pubescens",     "Betula pubescens",     "Betula pendula aggr.",
  "Galium", "verum",         "Galium verum",         "Galium verum",
  "Rosa",   "caesia",        "Rosa caesia",          "Rosa corymbifera aggr.",
  "Rosa",   "villosa",       "Rosa villosa",         "Rosa tomentosa aggr.",
  "Galium", "album",         "Galium album",         "Galium mollugo aggr.",
  "Rosa",   "corymbifera",   "Rosa corymbifera",     "Rosa corymbifera aggr.",
  "Rosa",   "glauca",        "Rosa glauca",          "Rosa glauca",
  "Galium", "megalospermum", "Galium megalospermum", "Galium megalospermum",
)

dat_b <- tibble::tribble(
  ~complete_name3,          ~some_value,
  "Betula pendula",         30L,
  "Betula pubescens",       93L,
  "Rosa pendulina",         76L,
  "Rosa canina aggr.",      36L,
  "Galium odoratum",        14L,
  "Galium verum",           66L,
  "Galium boreale",         16L,
  "Galium rotundifolium",   43L,
  "Galium uliginosum",      51L,
  "Galium palustre",        28L,
  "Galium aparine",         51L,
  "Galium megalospermum",   13L,
  "Galium anisophyllon",    49L,
  "Galium mollugo aggr.",   69L,
  "Galium pumilum",         92L,
  "Rosa arvensis",          94L,
  "Galium rubrum",          68L,
  "Galium lucidum",         11L,
  "Galium sylvaticum",      88L,
  "Rosa rubiginosa aggr.",  99L,
  "Rosa tomentosa aggr.",   34L,
  "Rosa spinosissima",      57L,
  "Rosa multiflora",        22L,
  "Rosa corymbifera aggr.", 93L,
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could do two joins and coalesce: (in this case giving preference to a `complete_name2` match, since it comes first in the coalesce step)

```
library(dplyr)
dat_a %>%
  left_join(dat_b, by = c("complete_name2" = "complete_name3")) %>%
  left_join(dat_b, by = c("complete_name1" = "complete_name3")) %>%
  mutate(value = coalesce(some_value.x, some_value.y)) %>%
  select(-c(5:6))
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 19 × 5
   genus  species       complete_name2       complete_name1         value
   <chr>  <chr>         <chr>                <chr>                  <int>
 1 Galium mollugo       Galium mollugo       Galium mollugo aggr.      69
 2 Galium boreale       Galium boreale       Galium boreale            16
 3 Galium aparine       Galium aparine       Galium aparine            51
 4 Rosa   canina        Rosa canina          Rosa canina aggr.         36
 5 Galium pumilum       Galium pumilum       Galium pumilum aggr.      92
 6 Betula pendula       Betula pendula       Betula pendula aggr.      30
 7 Rosa   tomentosa     Rosa tomentosa       Rosa tomentosa aggr.      34
 8 Galium anisophyllon  Galium anisophyllon  Galium pumilum aggr.      49
 9 Galium thunbergianum Galium thunbergianum NA                        NA
10 Galium rotundifolium Galium rotundifolium Galium rotundifolium      43
11 Galium lucidum       Galium lucidum       Galium lucidum            11
12 Betula pubescens     Betula pubescens     Betula pendula aggr.      93
13 Galium verum         Galium verum         Galium verum              66
14 Rosa   caesia        Rosa caesia          Rosa corymbifera aggr.    93
15 Rosa   villosa       Rosa villosa         Rosa tomentosa aggr.      34
16 Galium album         Galium album         Galium mollugo aggr.      69
17 Rosa   corymbifera   Rosa corymbifera     Rosa corymbifera aggr.    93
18 Rosa   glauca        Rosa glauca          Rosa glauca               NA
19 Galium megalospermum Galium megalospermum Galium megalospermum      13
```

Or another way could be to pivot + join, and add that to the original data:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat_a %>% mutate(row = row_number()) -> dat_a_rows
left_join(dat_a_rows,
          dat_a_rows %>%
            pivot_longer(-row) %>%
            left_join(dat_b, by = c("value" = "complete_name3")) %>%
            drop_na() %>%
            distinct(row, some_value)
  )
```

Result

```
Joining with `by = join_by(row)`
# A tibble: 19 × 6
   genus  species       complete_name2       complete_name1           row some_value
   <chr>  <chr>         <chr>                <chr>                  <int>      <int>
 1 Galium mollugo       Galium mollugo       Galium mollugo aggr.       1         69
 2 Galium boreale       Galium boreale       Galium boreale             2         16
 3 Galium aparine       Galium aparine       Galium aparine             3         51
 4 Rosa   canina        Rosa canina          Rosa canina aggr.          4         36
 5 Galium pumilum       Galium pumilum       Galium pumilum aggr.       5         92
 6 Betula pendula       Betula pendula       Betula pendula aggr.       6         30
 7 Rosa   tomentosa     Rosa tomentosa       Rosa tomentosa aggr.       7         34
 8 Galium anisophyllon  Galium anisophyllon  Galium pumilum aggr.       8         49
 9 Galium thunbergianum Galium thunbergianum NA                         9         NA
10 Galium rotundifolium Galium rotundifolium Galium rotundifolium      10         43
11 Galium lucidum       Galium lucidum       Galium lucidum            11         11
12 Betula pubescens     Betula pubescens     Betula pendula aggr.      12         93
13 Galium verum         Galium verum         Galium verum              13         66
14 Rosa   caesia        Rosa caesia          Rosa corymbifera aggr.    14         93
15 Rosa   villosa       Rosa villosa         Rosa tomentosa aggr.      15         34
16 Galium album         Galium album         Galium mollugo aggr.      16         69
17 Rosa   corymbifera   Rosa corymbifera     Rosa corymbifera aggr.    17         93
18 Rosa   glauca        Rosa glauca          Rosa glauca               18         NA
19 Galium megalospermum Galium megalospermum Galium megalospermum      19         13
```

Answer (score 1):

With {powerjoin} you can use something very similar to the syntax you had in mind. You'll need the GitHub version though for now as I just corrected some bugs that broke this answer:

```
# devtools::install_github("moodymudskipper/powerjoin")
powerjoin::power_left_join(
  dat_a, 
  dat_b, 
  by = ~ .x$complete_name1 == .y$complete_name3 | .x$complete_name2 == .y$complete_name3
)
#> # A tibble: 19 × 6
#>    genus  species       complete_name2       complete_name1      compl…¹ some_…²
#>    <chr>  <chr>         <chr>                <chr>               <chr>     <int>
#>  1 Galium mollugo       Galium mollugo       Galium mollugo agg… Galium…      69
#>  2 Galium boreale       Galium boreale       Galium boreale      Galium…      16
#>  3 Galium aparine       Galium aparine       Galium aparine      Galium…      51
#>  4 Rosa   canina        Rosa canina          Rosa canina aggr.   Rosa c…      36
#>  5 Galium pumilum       Galium pumilum       Galium pumilum agg… Galium…      92
#>  6 Betula pendula       Betula pendula       Betula pendula agg… Betula…      30
#>  7 Rosa   tomentosa     Rosa tomentosa       Rosa tomentosa agg… Rosa t…      34
#>  8 Galium anisophyllon  Galium anisophyllon  Galium pumilum agg… Galium…      49
#>  9 Galium thunbergianum Galium thunbergianum <NA>                <NA>         NA
#> 10 Galium rotundifolium Galium rotundifolium Galium rotundifoli… Galium…      43
#> 11 Galium lucidum       Galium lucidum       Galium lucidum      Galium…      11
#> 12 Betula pubescens     Betula pubescens     Betula pendula agg… Betula…      93
#> 13 Galium verum         Galium verum         Galium verum        Galium…      66
#> 14 Rosa   caesia        Rosa caesia          Rosa corymbifera a… Rosa c…      93
#> 15 Rosa   villosa       Rosa villosa         Rosa tomentosa agg… Rosa t…      34
#> 16 Galium album         Galium album         Galium mollugo agg… Galium…      69
#> 17 Rosa   corymbifera   Rosa corymbifera     Rosa corymbifera a… Rosa c…      93
#> 18 Rosa   glauca        Rosa glauca          Rosa glauca         <NA>         NA
#> 19 Galium megalospermum Galium megalospermum Galium megalosperm… Galium…      13
#> # … with abbreviated variable names ¹​complete_name3, ²​some_value
```

Comment: Nice! I thought this might be a problem many others also have, so there must be a solution within ```join```.